# Dev container congelado

Tags: vscode, docker, devcontainer

Tengo descaragada la extensión de VS Code de Dev containers pero al momento de querer conectarme a estos me aparece lo siguiente:

```
[74 ms] Dev Containers 0.304.0 in VS Code 1.81.1 (6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794).
[73 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[98 ms] Start: Run: wsl -l -v
[364 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c echo ~
[674 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c cd '/home/chris' && /bin/sh
[697 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[850 ms] chris
[851 ms] 
[851 ms] Start: Run in host: getent passwd chris
[855 ms] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[857 ms] /home/chris
[857 ms] 
[858 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/chris/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node'
[859 ms] 
[859 ms] 
[859 ms] Exit code 1
[860 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/chris/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node'
[861 ms] 
[861 ms] 
[862 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/chris/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node_modules/node-pty/package.json'
[863 ms] 
[863 ms] 
[863 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/chris/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.304.0.js'
[865 ms] 
[865 ms] 
[871 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[872 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[872 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[2873 ms] Start: Run in Host: /bin/sh 
[10879 ms] userEnvProbe is taking longer than 10 seconds. Avoid waiting for user input in your shell's startup scripts. Continuing.
```

Simplemente se queda ahí y no inicia el dev container